# Why broadcast ping takes longer than host ping

Tags: networking, ping, broadcast

I have a simple question. 
I have read that when I'm pinging broadcast address in LAN every device responds to ICMP Echo Request and console shows first(quickest) response.

But when I pinged broadcast response time was about **10 times longer** than pinging one specified host. Why? Shouldn't the reponse time be similar to pinging specified host? Or maybe assumption that after broadcast ping console shows fastest response is wrong?

Comment: One factor could be that broadcasts are usually handled with lower priority by network-cards and routers. So other traffic will be handled first. Also the router has to relay the boradcast to all attached devices, if he uses some traffic-shaping it may be sending the broadcast with some delay to one device after another. But this is just speculation